# Every deployment to Heroku displays different errors

Tags: scala, heroku, playframework-2.2

These are my configuration files:

**build.properties**

```
sbt.version=0.13.0
```

**Build.sbt**

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "2.0" % "test"

libraryDependencies += "org.seleniumhq.selenium" % "selenium-java" % "2.39.0" % "test"

libraryDependencies += "org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % "1.9.5"

resolvers += Classpaths.typesafeResolver
```

**Build.scala**

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName         = "library"
  val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    // Add your project dependencies here,
    jdbc,
    anorm,
    cache,
    "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901.jdbc4"
  )


  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=conf/test.conf"
  )

}
```

You can see from these samples, [the first](http://pastebin.com/Man21jv3) and [second](http://pastebin.com/Man21jv3) deployment logs, that it always throws different errors everytime I do git push to heroku.

The errors are always somewhere along these lines:

> [warn]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
>   sbt.ResolveException: download failed: com.typesafe#config;1.0.2!config.jar(bundle)

or

> :::: ERRORS
>   SERVER ERROR: Service Unavailable url=http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/main/0.13.0/ivys/ivy.xml

Any idea what's happening and possible workaround?

Comment: looks like their local cache is failing. You might want to ping them if this is a production issue.

Comment: Just to confirm it: exactly the same happens to me, when I try to deploy my app (same sbt-version, different libraries...). Right now I do not have a solution, but I will keep trying...

Comment: Thank you for the reponse, wheaties. They're looking into it now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved after Heroku support looks into it. They had some issues with S3pository which is their service that helps serve build dependencies.